# Could Not call Oauth 2 from RestTemplate

Tags: spring, oauth-2.0, resttemplate

I tried to call oauth 2  using Spring RestTemplate but   ended up with this error  404 Not Found: [{"message":"no Route matched with those values"}]

below is my code .OauthRequest is class  created by me .

```
    String oauthurl = serverurl + GET_TOKEN;
    HttpHeaders headers = buildHeader();
    OauthRequest oathRequest = new OauthRequest();
    oathRequest.setClient_id(clientid);
    oathRequest.setClient_secret(clientsecret);
    oathRequest.setAuthenticated_userid(usercode);
    oathRequest.setScope(scope);
    oathRequest.setGrant_type(grantTypePassword);
    oathRequest.setProvision_key(key);
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    headers.set("Host", hostname);
    headers.set("Accept-Version", "1.0");
    headers.set("Content-Length", MAX_TRANSFER_SIZE);
   
    
    HttpEntity<OauthRequest> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(oathRequest, headers);
    ResponseEntity<OauthResponse> result = restTemplate.exchange(oauthurl, HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity,
            OauthResponse.class);
    return result.getBody();
```

Is  there any limitation on calling from RestTemplate rather than using OAuth2RestTemplate .My understanding is it will be achievable using  RestTemplate also.Must i use OAuth2RestTemplate ?Any help?

Comment: 404 means your URL is not correct. Check if the endpoint is correct or not.

Answer (score 0):

RestTemplate does not set hostname in

```
headers.set("Host", hostname);
```

Adding below it worked

```
System.setProperty("sun.net.http.allowRestrictedHeaders", "true");
```